# Comment environment not working with complex structures inside it

Tags: environments, comments

I am a math teacher and would love to use latex to prepare exercise to send to my students.
I usually do something like this:

```
\section{exercise}
    text text text
    \begin{equation}
    some equation here
    \end{equation}

\section{Solution}
here is contained the solution of the exercise; 
It includes formulas, equation environment, graphics and so on: for example something like
    \begin{equation*}
      \begin{aligned}
         &x+2y^2=5\\
         &5x-2y=7
      \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}
```

Problem comes when I try to use the comment package in a way like the following:
In the preamble I set

```
    \usepackage{comment}
    \excludecomment{SOLUTIONS}
   %\includecomment{SOLUTIONS}
```

Then I use a SOLUTIONS environment just befone the Solution section. This is intended to produce just the text and, in a second moment, I will swap the comment between `\includecomment{SOLUTIONS}` and `\excludecomment{SOLUTIONS}` in the preamble to generate a pdf which include also the solution, not only the trace. I use something like the following:

```
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{SOLUTIONS}
%\includecomment{SOLUTIONS}

\begin{document}    
\section{exercise}
        text text text
        \begin{equation}
        some equation here
        \end{equation}
    
    \begin{SOLUTIONS}
    \section{Solution}
    here is contained the solution of the exercise; 
    It includes formulas, equation environment, graphics and so on: for example something like
        \begin{equation*}
          \begin{aligned}
             &x+2y^2=5\\
             &5x-2y=7
          \end{aligned}
        \end{equation*}
    \end{SOLUTIONS}
\end{document}
```

If I try to compile the document, I get an error (I use texstudio, updated to the latest version; also the comment package is updated to the latest version).
Same error happens if I use the standard `\begin{comment}...\end{comment}` instead of the custom SOLUTIONS environment.
Elsewhere i read it is not possible to nest environment in Latex: should this be the problem? Is there some workaround other than comment/uncomment any single line of code on the solution area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as though environments defined with `\includecomment` and `\excludecomment` are sensitive to whitespace. After removing the indentation from the `SOLUTIONS` environment, the file compiles without any errors.

Here is the full file:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\excludecomment{SOLUTIONS}
%\includecomment{SOLUTIONS}

\begin{document}
\section{exercise}
        text text text
        \begin{equation}
        some equation here
        \end{equation}

\begin{SOLUTIONS}
\section{Solution}
here is contained the solution of the exercise;
It includes formulas, equation environment, graphics and so on: for example something like
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
     &x+2y^2=5\\
     &5x-2y=7
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{SOLUTIONS}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Really useful. I could have read better the documentation on the comment package to find the solution, anyway thanks for pointing it out.